# Python Pandas: Find the total sales value of the category 'Office Supplies' after combining the dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

How do we find sales for Office Supplies Category?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOtCI.jpg)

Comment: you usually start with some code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming (and I'm having to assume a lot) that you want to find the total of the column 'Sales_x' for all lines where the category is 'Office Supplies', then it's the following.

```
df3[df3['Category'] == 'Office Supplies']['Sales_x'].sum()
```

Hopefully even if my assumption is wrong, this will put you on the right lines for whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Yes, it did put me on the right path! I solved it.